# Merging java.util.Properties in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I have a method that takes a `java.util.Properties` object as a constructor argument. It's currently being constructed through Spring as such (see [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29)):

```
<bean id="myObj" class="myClass">
    <constructor-arg>
        <value>
            prop1=1
            prop2=2
        </value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Now I want to extract this `<value>...</value>` block so that I can create other `Properties` beans that inherit from these basic properties but override/delete/add some properties. Note that I want to keep the `<value></value>` format if possible.

I tried to use `<util:properties>`, however, there seem to be no way to use the same format as in `<value></value>`.

I also tried to use

```
<bean id="test" class="java.util.Properties">
    <constructor-args>
        <value>
             test1=1
             test2=2
        </value>
    </constructor-args>
</bean>
```

It seems that even if there is a copy constructor in `java.util.Properties`, that doesn't work (gives an empty Properties object). Furthermore, if I have a java.util.Properties bean, how would I override/extend it with another properties list/bean?

Comment: If you happen to know where to find the documentation for util:properties that would be appreciated.

Comment: The documentation for util:properties is here: http://static.springsource.org/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html, I have added an answer also now

Comment: This documentation is extremely incomplete and doesn't even show the supported tags inside of the util:properties tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like people reviewing my edit are not very helpful and don't understand it. Therefore I'll post the full answer here.

```
<bean name="props" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
 <property name="properties">
    <value>
        test1=1
        test2=2
    </value>

</property>
</bean>

<bean name="props2" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
 <property name="propertiesArray">
  <list>
      <ref bean="props">
      <value>
           test1=OVERRIDE!
      </value>
  </list>
 </property>
</bean>

<bean id="myObj" class="myClass">
 <constructor-arg ref="props2">
 </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<bean name="props" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="properties">
        <value>
            test1=1
            test2=2
        </value>

    </property>
</bean>
```

and then refer to the common set of properties elsewhere:

```
<bean id="myObj" class="myClass">
    <constructor-arg ref="props">
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: I'm already using the PropertiesFactoryBean to merge my Properties, but I find it rather ugly. I'll edit your answer to include the full details.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I am don't have permission to accept your updates, if  you can make the changes once more, I can review and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

With Spring 3 you can do this :

```
<util:properties id="myProperties">
    <prop key="test1Key">test1Value</prop>
    <prop key="test2Key">test2Value</prop>
</util:properties>

<bean id="myObj" class="myClass">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="myProperties" />
</bean>
```